# How to create multiple indicator variables with for loop in R?

Tags: r

Basically here are the codes I have used to create 8 new missing value indicator variables in `GSS_sub`, and I want to transform these into a for loop.

```
GSS_sub$NUMPETS_mis <- 0
GSS_sub$NUMPETS_mis[is.na(GSS_sub$NUMPETS)] <- 1

GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis <- 0
GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis[is.na(GSS_sub$NUMPETS)] <- 1

GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis <- 0
GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis[is.na(GSS_sub$NUMPETS)] <- 1

GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis <- 0
GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis[is.na(GSS_sub$NUMPETS)] <- 1

GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis <- 0
GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis[is.na(GSS_sub$NUMPETS)] <- 1

GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis <- 0
GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis[is.na(GSS_sub$NUMPETS)] <- 1

GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis <- 0
GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis[is.na(GSS_sub$NUMPETS)] <- 1
```

Comment: Why are you over-writing `GSS_sub$HHTYPE1_mis` everytime? It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a loop. Define the new columns that you want to create (`cols`) and use `as.integer(is.na())` to generate 1 for `NA` value in `GSS_sub$NUMPETS` and 0 otherwise.

```
cols <- c('NUMPETS_mis', 'HHTYPE1_mis')
GSS_sub[cols] <- as.integer(is.na(GSS_sub$NUMPETS))
```